# Windows 10 - Recovery loop

Tags: windows-10, system-recovery

How do I bypass this?

The message reads:

```
Recovery

Your PC/Device needs to be repaired.
A component of the OS has expired

File: \windows\system32\winload.exe
Error Code: 0xc0000605

You'll need to use recovery tools.
```

I even created a bootable windows 7 usb from my mac, but it doesn't boot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the error you describe, your installation of Windows 10, has expired and the only solution is a clean installation of Windows.

> The expiration dates for Windows 10 Technical Preview vary by build
>   number.  The table below summarizes the expiration dates for each of
>   the builds Microsoft has released so far.
>
> (Per Microsoft: Dates are subject to change.)

[image]

**Expiration warnings:**

> Approximately 2 weeks before a build’s license expires, you will start
>   getting warnings that this build will expire and that you should
>   update to the most recent build.

[image]

**License expiration date:**

> When the build reaches the license expiration date, the system will
>   automatically reboot every three hours (actually more than ten minutes
>   short of 3 hours). I you should be away from the computer when this
>   happens, any open applications and the information they contains will
>   be lost when the system reboots.

**Windows will stop booting date:**

> This is what you can expect to see when power on the computer and you
>   attempt to load Windows.  Pressing the Enter key or the F8 option or
>   rebooting will do you no good. It’s an endless loop back to the same
>   error message.

[image]

**Source:** [Page Start: What happens when a build reaches its expiration date](http://www.pagestart.com/win10tpbuildexp041215.html)

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you get the error is completely explained [by @Ramhound's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/915564/windows-10-recovery-loop/915598#915598). And probably the best solution is to re-install your Windows. However, changing the system date in the BIOS to an earlier date (03/01/15) should give you access to the system, after which you can update it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer (Nov 6, 2015) added a useful point about disabling the internet connection after changing system date in BIOS.  However, neither the original question nor any answer so far has specified whether or not Windows 10 was *activated* prior to receiving the Error Code.  For the original questioner, in May, activation might still have been possible, but if the Insider Preview was not activated prior to commercial release date, later attempts to update a Preview install will fail, as Microsoft ended independent activation for the Insider program.
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2950050/windows/no-more-new-windows-10-insiders-for-now.html

If upgraded from an **activated** install of Windows 7 or 8, or one activated early in the Insider Preview program, changing the date in BIOS and unplugging the internet might get you in long enough to plug back in and then update Windows 10 online, or to install a current release from media inside an installed system.  I found I was able to get in and "Reset" Windows 10 to temporarily lose the error, but not to update the system without being activated.

Answer (score -1):

Starting Windows 10 Insider Preview with expired license in Mac Parallel Desktop:

1. Mount your windows image (Windows 10.pvm) :

   - search Windows 10.pvm
   - open in finder
   - right click the pvm file, mount with Parallels Mounter
2. Find C:\Windows\bootstat.dat
3. Rename to _bootstat.dat
4. Unmount Windows drive from Finder
5. Change the date of Mac to 2013
6. Start Windows 10

Note that this step is needed to install the latest build of Windows 10 Insider Preview

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question, which has nothing to do with Mac Parallel Desktop.

Comment: In addition, your suggestion of changing the date duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score -1):

okay, i had the version installed on one of my dev pc's i fired it up and found a workaround, its temporary if you need to get you files, as well as maybe have an easier way of updating the driver that creates that chaos.

1. on boot, launch your system preferences
2. change the date on the system to reflect it to the previous year (this resolves all the versions)
3. save your settings
4. on restart you computer should start normally
5. before you log-in, disable your wifi/internet connection or it will catch a hangup when the connection updates the date on your system and it pretty much crashes. (if you already did this, don't worry just restart the process)
6. now you should be in, do this as many times as you need as the system will restart itself at some point. (really find a way to just ditch this version of the OS)

cheers!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.